# How to dynamically style the display a pdf document using pdf.js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

I integrated pdf viewer in my app using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Input } from "reactstrap";
import { searchBarStyle } from "../../common/reactSelectStyle";

export class PDFViewer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pdf: null,
    
    };
 
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var pdfjsLib = window["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"];
    var url = this.props.pdfUrl;
    // var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({
      url: url,
      disableAutoFetch: true,
      disableStream: true,
    });
    loadingTask.promise.then((pdf) => {
      this.setState({ pdf });
    });
  }
 
  render() {
    if (!!this.state.pdf) {
      this.state.pdf.getPage(this.state.currentPage).then((page) => {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("pdf_renderer");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var viewport = page.getViewport(this.state.zoom);

        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        canvas.height = viewport.height;

        page.render({
          canvasContext: ctx,
          viewport: viewport,
        });
      });
    }

    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div id="canvas_container" className="canvas-container">
              <canvas id="pdf_renderer"> </canvas>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
     
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PDFViewer);
```

This works perfectly fine.
The problem is that if if the document dimensions are larger than the screen (For eg, on the phone), the document will overflow from the sides and the user can't even scroll to see the hidden parts:
[image]

Setting the `canvas` size to the window width and height doesn't work, nor does it make sense:

```
 canvas.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

If the document is larger than the screen, then it will get cut to fit the screen size.

So the bottom line,
I'd like to display the document with the correct height-to-width ratio and completely within the screen limits just like when you open it in a pdf reader app.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I just added width: "100%",and height: "100%",

```
      <canvas
        id="pdf_renderer"
        className="canvas"
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
```

And it kinda works.